# Provider com.bea.xml.stream.MXParserFactory not found

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

Anyone come across this error when trying to import a WSDL in Flex builder 3?

Seems it only occurs when trying to import a WCF based service which has 'virtual' endpoints...

Some digging around makes me think Flex has trouble parsing the wsdl (however standard web services work fine).

A bug has been opened for months and still no reply from Adobe:

http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-13542

Answer (score 1):

I am using Flex Builder 3 and the solution found here http://poradowski.com/fb/  that was mentioned in the adobe bug base at FB-13542 worked for me. I just backed up the com.adobe.flexbuilder.axis2_3.0.214193.jar file and put the updated jar file in it's place. Restarted Flex Builder and was able to import our wsdl that had the "policy" tags in it.

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when you are using the StAX API, and you do not have a StAX implementation in your classpath. See http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=117971

I am not too familiar with Flex - but even if you are not using StAX directly, it may be using it under the covers.